# rspec check array elements for instances of numbers

Tags: rspec

How to check if the elements of arrays are containing only numbers (integers)?

```
 describe "#draw" do
   it "returns an array" do
     expect(@lottery_tip.draw).to be_a_kind_of Array
   end
   it "has six elements" do
     expect(@lottery_tip.draw.count).to eq(6)
   end
   it "s elements are only numbers" do
     expect(@lottery_tip.draw).to ???
   end
 end
```

My simple LotteryTip Class works but i'm wondering how to check the type of the elements in that returning array...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`all` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/all-matcher).

```
expect(@tip.draw).to all(be_an(Integer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is best or at least good practice but i defined an own method in the before :each do block:

```
def is_number?
  @tip.all? { |x| x.is_a? Integer }
end
```

And so i can check in the it block:

```
   it "s elements are only numbers" do
     expect(is_number?).to eq(true)
   end
```